# Can't find my saved xml file in Magento

Tags: xml, file, magento

I've been working on a method to save an xml file when an order is placed in my Magento portal. Everything appears to be saving without error except when the method is completed, I can't find my xml file anywhere

Does anybody know where it's saving the file? Or is Magento secretly going in after the method completes and removing the file?

```
try {
    Mage::log('Attempting to save xml...');
    $xml->asXML("test.xml");
    Mage::log('Xml saved!');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log('Problem encountered');
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```

I'm also converting the xml to a string and emailing it to myself and everything looks to be in check there. According to the logs, the file is saving without error, as I'm getting a "Xml saved!" message in them. But when I check the directory of this Module, there's no xml file. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the directory with index.php in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's numerous errors in PHP that aren't exception which might stop the above code from running (depending on your [PHP error settings](http://alanstorm.com/php_error_reporting) and Magento's developer mode settings).  The most common reason a file wouldn't be written is file permissions, and this doesn't raise an exception, it just raises an error.

I'd drop in the following before your `asXml` call

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); 
ini_set('log_errors','1');
ini_set('error_log','/tmp/my-custom-php-error-log.log');
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

echo "The current working PHP directory is " . getcwd() . "\n" . "<br/>" . "\n";
$xml->asXML("test.xml");
```

This will tell you where PHP is trying to save the file, as well as crank the error reporting to maximum with a custom log.  This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: While I couldn't locate the my-custom-php-error-log.log after it executed, I was able to track down where the test.xml was being saved thanks to the getcwd command. "The current working PHP directory is /home/edencom/public_html". I suppose the error log was never created since it made the file. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Rob That's right, the error log would only be created if an error was generated (and your server admins hadn't disabled ini_set)